# wp_mail attachment not working

Tags: plugins, email, wp-mail

Hello I am trying to send mail with some attachment using with wordpress `wp_mail` functionality but I am not getting attachment in my mailbox.

Can you please check my bellow code and guide me where I am wrong. You can see I am seeding image in attachment.

```
<?php
    $to  = 'my@email.com';
    $subject = 'WordPress wp_mail';
    $message = '
    <html>
    <body>
        <table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">
          <tr>Hello WordPress</tr>
        </table>          
    </body>
    </html>
    ';

    $attachments = array( 'http://sitename/project/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/uploads/sample_photo_01.jpg' );
    //$attachments = array(WP_CONTENT_DIR  . '/uploads/'.$_FILES["myfile"]["name"]);
    $headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers[] = 'From: '.get_option( 'blogname' ).' <'.get_option( 'admin_email' ).'>';

    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments );
?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are normal emails from WordPress working?

Comment: My email functionality is working. Only thing is that I am not getting attachments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Attachments should always use the absolute filesystem path.

Also to change the `Content-Type` of the email you should use the `wp_mail_content_type` filter.

```
<?php
function my_custom_email() {
    $to  = 'my@email.com';
    $subject = 'WordPress wp_mail';
    $message = '
    <html>
    <body>
        <table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">
          <tr>Hello WordPress</tr>
        </table>          
    </body>
    </html>
    ';

    $attachments = array(  WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/my-plugin/uploads/sample_photo_01.jpg' );
    $headers[] = 'From: '.get_option( 'blogname' ).' <'.get_option( 'admin_email' ).'>';
    add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'my_custom_email_content_type' );
    return wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments );
}

function my_custom_email_content_type() {
    return 'text/html';
}
```

I have placed the entire code in a function so that the `wp_mail_content_type` filter applies only to this email.

Sources:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_mail_content_type

Comment: Hi I have tried your function code in and check but now I am not able to get mail.

Comment: @Manan I have made a slight change to the code. See what the function returns - `var_dump( my_custom_email() );`

Comment: No mail and getting `bool(true)`

Comment: @Manan Were you previously receiving mails using the code in your question?

Comment: Hey now I got the mail but not found attachment.

Comment: @Manan Make sure `sample_photo_01.jpg` exists in the specified directory. Is the email properly formatted in HTML? Open the headers of this email and check if `Content-Disposition: attachment;` exists.

Comment: Thanks brother. Now I am getting attachment from my mail. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code

```
  $attachments = array( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/file_to_attach.zip' );
   $headers = 'From: My Name <myname@example.com>' . "\r\n";
   wp_mail('test@example.org', 'subject', 'message', $headers, $attachments );
```

I get it from http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail

Comment: Yes I have made code from that page but not working.

Comment: You can remove    $headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

Comment: I have `uploads` folder inside `my-plugin` so how to retrieve from that folder? Is it use for `WP_CONTENT_DIR`?

Comment: Any special reason for that. I have no idea.

Comment: WP_CONTENT_DIR is a constant get wp-content folder path only.For plugin you can get the plugin folder path by plugin_dir_url() https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_url

Comment: We can make it path dynamic later. At this time we can pass static image path for testing purposes. I hope you can understand.

Comment: You should use attachment as absolute path not as external path

Comment: I have tried with `A.Jesin` code as he mentions above with dynamic path but still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Better to use `get_home_path();` - [WordPress Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_home_path/)

```
$attachments = array( get_home_path() . '/wp-content/themes/your-theme/uploads/sample_photo_01.jpg');
```

This gets the absolute filesystem path to the root of the WordPress installation, all you need to do from there is navigate to where you image / file is located.